# Frequent locations not remembering any location?

Tags: ios, privacy, iphone

I had this option activated months ago and it registered my home location and some other random location. But I decided to turn all system services off and delete it's history.

Two weeks ago, I have turned system services back on and only activated frequent locations . But unfortunately no location has been registered yet, and I have been going to work everyday at the same time (+- 5 mins ).

Not sure why this is happening, how can I fix this ?

**EDIT**

It's been 10 days since I posted this, and no frequent locations have been saved yet.

Comment: "system services" or "location services"? Also, has this cleared up yet?